# Parameter passing to subroutine x64 inline assembly(Vc++ 2015 with Intel c++ compiler 2017)

Tags: inline-assembly

I coded

```
main()  
{
  unsigned char *memory; 
  unsigned int a=15;  
  float sigma=5.0f;  


  gaussian_filter();
```

}

```
gaussian_filter()  
{  
    unsigned __int64 evacuate_rbp;      
    unsigned __int64 evacuate_rsp;  

 __asm
 {
         mov eax, a
         ...         
         mov evacuate_rbp, rbp
         mov evacuate_rsp, rsp
         ...

         mov rsp, memory
         ...

         movss xmm0, sigma

         ....    

         mov rbp, evacuate_rbp
         mov rsp, evacuate_rsp 
      }       
}
```

I want to non-parameter passing to use rbp and rsp registers as an address index of memory. 
In Build with Intel C++ compiler,  error is occured. Why?.

Comment: What error happened?

Comment: The location of stack variables is not guaranteed.  In fact, in an optimized build, the compiler would probably not even include `a` and `sigma` in the generated output, since it 'knows' they are not being used.  In other words, what you are trying to do is a bad idea that will only work sometimes.  By accident.